# Right way to communicate portable Fortran data types with MPI

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

Which is the right way to define MPI data types in a portable way, based on variables that were defined using "kind(...)"? I am using OpenMPI 4.0.2

My MPI calls look a little something like this:

```
use mpi_f08
implicit none
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = KIND(1.0d0)
REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: buffer
allocate(buffer(10))
!...
call MPI_ISEND(buffer(:),10,MPI_REAL8,tgt,id,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ierr)
```

In this example I used MPI_REAL8 as a placeholder. How do I define an MPI data type that equals the data type of my "buffer" variable?
Bonus points for a solution that also works with MPI reductions.

Edit:
Is this really a duplicate? I read some of the MPI documentation (and the question marked as a duplicate) before asking, and what I understood was that dealing with selected_real_kind is not the same as dealing with kind(1.0d0). And what about the bonus question concerning MPI reductions?

Comment: In a hurry but look at  MPI_Type_create_f90_real and related

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? I read some of the MPI documentation before asking, and what I understood was that dealing with selected_real_kind is not the same as dealing with kind(1.0d0)

Comment: If you are using `kind(1d0)` then you can happily use `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` to refer to them.  But if you need something more general, a mapping between the kinds and `MPI_` constants or byte counts, then that's the other question.

Comment: Note the question linked to is 6 years old, and it's my impression that the support for MPI_Type_create_f90_real is better now